# How to avoid extra shell when ssh -f?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ssh, solaris

If I do

```
ssh -f 10.10.47.47 "/opt/omni/bin/mbuffer -4 -v 0 -q -I 8024 | /usr/sbin/zfs receive tank/test"
```

then I have to press `CTRL-D` to exit an extra shell that have been spawned on the Linux host, where I ran the `ssh` command.

If I do

```
ssh -f 10.10.47.47 "sleep 10s"
```

and then try to `CTRL-D` than the Linux host hangs until the `sleep` command exits on the remote host. Very weird behaviour, which I wouldn't expect since `-f` was used.

**Question**

Is it possible to avoid this extra shell on the host where the `ssh` command is executed?

Comment: `ssh -f ...` is roughly equivalent to `ssh -n ... & `; after it asks for a password, it runs in the background and you get your shell prompt back while ssh continues to run. Are you seeing something other than that?

Comment: Very interesting. If that do that, and then `CTRL-D` then it hangs until the remote program have exited.

Comment: When you are ssh'ed into a system, you sometimes won't be immediately disconnected when you exit the shell; the ssh daemon will wait until all background jobs created by that shell finish. Those background jobs could be anything. In your case it was due to your running ssh's that forked off a copy into the background, but I've seen it happen with other programs I started with `&`. I think it's session-id related, but I haven't looked into it too deeply.

Comment: Does it help using nohup?